# How to send HTTP POST request to Firebase

Tags: swift, curl, firebase-realtime-database

How can I send a simple post request to Firebase RealtimeDatabase? Currently Database secrets are deprecated. 
I am using Vapor + Swift on server, Firebase SDK requires Node JS or Java.

This method is deprectate.
`curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/auth-example.json?auth=CREDENTIAL'`

Comment: I think they have iOS SDK, supporting swift.

Comment: The up-to-date documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data. The API is almost the same.